# Can we iterate values from excel to POST json request one by one in SOAPUI. If yes please share a piece of code

Tags: rest, api, soapui, data-driven

Can we iterate values from excel to POST json request one by one in SOAPUI?
It should get the response for each and every request from iterated value.
Kindly share groovy script to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

No code is needed as such. You need to create a TestCase, in which you have:

```
DataSource TestStep
Rest Request TestStep
DataSource Loop TestStep
```

The DataSource should be set to point towards your Excel input file, and you should input the column names. Make sure your Excel file i saved in the rather ancient 97 format. (This may no longer be true, but for a long time, this has been the only type of Excel file that SoapUI was able to work with.)

Your Rest Request should naturally import and use the columns from your input file that are relevant.

Your DataSource Loop should just send the script back to your Rest Request.

This will make the script loop until it runs out of data in your input file.

Comment: Hi,

Steen's answer, IMHO, is the right one and I've upvoted that.  I use SoapUI's data-driven functionality on a daily basis.  It's really intuitive and takes little time to test lots of different combinations.  Smartbear's site provides a straightforward explanation with screenshots.  However, this functionality isn't available in the free version.  Only the licensed version.  If you have the free version, there are already several previously answered solutions on SO that solely use Groovy script.  Have a look.

Comment: Hi @Chris- Can you send me the link for the same.

Comment: I'll leave the research side to you.  If you have any problems with the solution you try, I can help then.